# Power query adding expandable year column

Tags: powerbi

I have created a custom column and I want this column to be expandable. How do I make it expandable?

[image]

and when I click on the error in the image it shows the below error

> **Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Table to type Function.
>
> Details:
>       Value=Table
>       Type=Type**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

TransformColumns() is your friend.

As [BICCOUNTANT](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2017/07/25/how-to-expand-a-column-that-cannot-be-expanded-in-power-bi-and-power-query-in-excel/) showed us, you can use this to expand columns

```
Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{“Column1”, each if Value.Is(_, type list) then _ else {_} }} )
```

tables

```
Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{“Column1”, each if Value.Is(_, type table) then _ else #table({“Column1”}, {{_}} ) }} )
```

and lists

```
Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{“Column1”, each if Value.Is(_, type record) then _ else [a=_] }} )
```

Comment: Hi,I already see that code in advanced editor. I'm confused where to add it

Comment: let
    YearParamList = {2016,2017,2018},
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(YearParamList, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "YearValues"}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "EPL_Match_Details", each EPL_Match_Data([YearValues])),
    #"Added Custom" = "Table.TransformColumns(EPL_Match_Data, {{2016,each if Value.Is(_, type list) then _ else {_} }} )"
in
    #"Added Custom"